# How does a map from permutahedra to associahedra factor through multiplihedra?

Tags: co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology, ra.rings-and-algebras, convex-polytopes, operads

Let $P_i$ denote permutahedra, $K_i$ associahedra and $J_i$ multiplihedra. In their famous paper on operadic diagonals, Saneblidze and Umble use a projection $p_i: P_i \to K_{i+1}$ which factors as $P_i \to J_i \to K_{i+1}$. The projection is as follows: we index faces of $P_i$ with *leveled* planar binary trees with $i+1$ leaves, and we index faces of $K_{i+1}$ with planar binary trees with $i+1$ leaves; so $p_i$ is by disregarding levels.

However, one labelling of $J_i$'s faces that I know is by appropriately *painted* planar binary trees with $i$ leaves, not $i+1$ (as in Forcey https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.3226). So I am having a problem understanding the factorization above. How does one see painted trees with $i$ leaves as equivalence classes of leveled trees with $i+1$ leaves?

(In case $i=3$, $P_3$ and $J_3$ are both hexagons, so the equivalence classes are just with one element - there should be a bijection, but which bijection?)

Comment: Maybe use the level of the unique inner vertex under the rightmost leaf of the leveled tree to fix the painting height ?